# jQuery Selector nth-child(n) under unknown level?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

For the 2nd `<h3>World!</h3>` in this sample scenario (**Please note `<..>` elements are unknown elements at all levels**):

```
<div></div>
<div class="class1">
    <..>
        <h3>Hello!</h3>
        <..>
            <h3>World!</h3>
        </..>
    </..>
</div>
```

Lets **assume we know only**:

- `Top Parent <div class="class1">` and `Target Child Elements <h3>`
- Middle levels are `unknowns`. Can be `<p>` or `<div>` or `<ul>` whatever.

So I want to use `nth-child(n)` selector. But I can't use like this:

```
$("div.class1 h3:nth-child(2)").html();
```

Now i'm realized is the `nth-child(n)` selector can select only the `Direct Child` of the parent element, rite?

Can i make it work by using `nth-child(n)` selector?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "definitely".

Comment: side note: header elements should not live within paragraphs or spans, so that might be messing with your jQuery calls. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/9pCuz/1/

Comment: sure would save a lot of time if you provide more defined scope up front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("div.class1 h3:eq(1)").html();
```

Select all `h3`'s under `div.class1` depth first, and then take the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
$('h3').eq(1).html();
```

In this example, jQuery returns an array of `h3` elements, and you're selecting the second item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`$("div.class1 h3")` will give you an array of the two h3. SO you could use `$("div.class1 h3")[1]` to get the second matching element.

Comment: this will give you the HTML element, not the jQuery element. Use .eq(1) to get a jQuery element

Answer (score 0):

Find all elements within class containing h3, isolate last of each

DEMO: (nested version)  http://jsfiddle.net/3daHU/1/

```
$("div.class1 *:has(h3)").each(function(){   
    $(this).children('h3:last').css('color','red')
})
```